# Can't construct a JTable with int[][] and String[] arguments

Tags: java, swing, jtable

The constructor JTable is giving me an error that says:

> "The constructor JTable(int[][], String[]) is undefined"

although it has a constructor `JTable(Object[][], Object[])`  (`Calcul.apartements` is of the type `int[][]`)

```
    String[] colonnes = {"Appartements", "Prix Milion de Cts", "Tempd duTrajet/C.v (en min)", "Superficie (en m2)", "Etage"};
    table  = new JTable(Calcul.appartements, colonnes);
```

Comment: `int` is not an `Object`. Either trying defining the array as `Object[][]` and put `int`s into it or use `Integer[][]` instead

Comment: @AJNeufeld What I intended to say and what my fingers said seem to be at  odds far to often :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. alter your `Calcul.appartements` data to be `Object[][]` or `Integer[][]` (as mentioned by @MadProgrammer in the comments)
2. Implement your own table model.

Implementing the table model might be as simple as:

```
TableModel dataModel = new AbstractTableModel() {
        public int getColumnCount() { return colonnes.length; }
        public String getColumnName(int col) { return colonnes[col]; }
        public int getRowCount() { return Calcul.appartements.length; }
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { Calcul.appartements[row][col]; }
    };
JTable table = new JTable(dataModel);
```